# Cloud Functions on Firestore for Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm relatively new to Firestore and I am currently trying to build a Flutter app on it. I have hit a roadblock where I realize that I must utilized Firestore Cloud Functions in order to perform server-side data manipulation.

Unfortunately, there are not a lot of great resources and videos describing the process to set this up (at least for someone super new to software development like me). However, I was able to find this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0 that goes over how to set up a Firestore app using Typscript. As such, I have two questions:

1. Will setting up the environment to write cloud functions be the same here for Firestore as it will be for Firebase?
2. Do I want to write these functions in Javascript or Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. When you use Cloud Firestore, you're essentially using Firebase, and the setup for Cloud Functions is the same between them. If you run into problems, post a questions with the [minimal steps needed to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. That's your call, as recommending one technology over another is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. That said, most developers coming from a background with strictly typed languages may prefer typescript.